# Speed up Python Poetry dependancy resolution

Tags: python-poetry

The dependency resolution of my Poetry environments frequently takes >20min. My personal best is 6hrs!!! I'm clearly doing something wrong. Running `poetry lock -vvv` I notice various versions of `sdist` get downloaded this takes several seconds each time. Additionally, I see to following messages a repeating
[image]

or

[image]

It seems this is where the resolution takes the longest. I am using a private PyPi server as my secondary

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "private_pypi"
url = "https://pypi.private_pypi.com.au/simple"
secondary = true

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pypi-public"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple/"
```

I also see a message earlier in the logs `Private PyPi: Response url ... differs from request url ...` not sure if this is related.

There is an extensive thread in the [Poetry Git issue 2094](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2094) that seems to indicate many of the resolution woes are out of Poetry's hands. Not sure if this is the case for me.

I'm simply looking for some next steps to try and speed things up.

Will nailing down versions in my `pyproject.toml` (ie: using `==` not `^` or `>=`) help? Is there something immediately obvious that I'm doing wrong? How many goats should I sacrifice?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Use `>=` where appropriate. See warnings.

To speed things up, try setting minimum versions in your `pyproject.toml` as you mentioned. Personally, i like somewhat open-ended dependencies so `poetry lock` will fix CVEs (security vulnerabilities)  with little to no work. However, to greatly speed up dependency resolution, I set the current version (from my successfully resolved `poetry.lock` / `poetry show --tree`) as the minimum. Obvious warning that this could break dependencies if others import your code! You're saying "i need this latest version" when in reality you don't and just want faster resolution. So don't do this for open-source code. And either way, add a comment as to why, and what the minimum version really is. Especially if a certain minimum is required due to a CVE, which you should mention in the comment.

For your example, I don't see the value of `sdist` but from the images you posted, this would mean:

```
numpy = ">=1.21.2"  # Our code requires minimum version >=[enter here] due to CVE 1234
pandas = ">=1.4.2"  # Minimum version to speed up resolution. Will work with any 1.0.0+
```

Some people like to use `^` (don't allow for version upgrades, see https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/) instead of the  open-ended `>=` min version (no max) but if you have decent unit tests, you should be able to detect any breaking updates.

I would also recommend ONLY listing libraries you import in your own code in `pyproject.toml` so that you don't end up installing libraries you don't need when a pypi library switches (say pandas stops using numpy, and switched to some shiny new library in this theoretical example).

For example, if you don't import anything from `numpy`, and it's only installed because of `pandas`, then only set:

```
pandas = ">=1.4.2"  # Minimum version to speed up resolution. Will work with any 1.0.0+. This will also set a minimum version for numpy. See `poetry show tree` for more details
```

Why? Because pandas comes with its own dependencies, and you setting one may later break the tree.

With that warning against setting external library's requirements, there are cases where you may want to force a min dependency just to speed up the resolution process. Imagine the library said `numpy = ">= 1.0"`. Then it's possible that attempting to resolve pandas (in this example) would download the requirements for every version since 1.0.0 before making a decision (especially on failures to resolve).

I was able to get my `poetry lock` to go from 3 minutes -> 19 seconds by setting two libraries!

Secondary warning: using this method will slowly drift over time and get back to terrible dependency resolution. When that happens, you'll probably want to increase the minimum version (around once a year), depending on how quickly your main external libraries get updated.

Which libraries should you ">= pin"? Those that take the longest (or go through the highest number of versions) in `poetry lock -vvv`.
Play around and see which libraries are worth setting values for vs the amount of time it saves. Avoid setting versions for things that resolved quickly; there are many drawbacks! Note that this is also a problem with pip's `requirements.txt` and is not unique to poetry.

Answer (score -2):

First run:

```
poetry cache clear pypi --all
```

Then run

```
poetry lock
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue?

Comment: It does not solve the issue.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I asked the same question on the Git issue thread. One potential reason from **johnthagen** is a corrupted cache caused by killing a Poetry install. [link](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2094#issuecomment-1247952378)